# Save jQuery UI Sortable on Wordpress

Tags: jquery

I have basic jQuery UI sortable code that works perfectly. I just want the position of each item to save when a user changes it.

I am using Wordpress multisite version 3.8.1 and each site will have it's own sortable area so it needs to save in a different database for each site.

I did see [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-drag-and-drop-jquery-ui-sortables-front-end-layout-ed) but it isn't quite what  I was looking for. It might help though.

HTML:

```
    `<ul id="sortable">
     <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
     </ul>`
```

jQuery:

```
    `<script>
     $(function() {
     $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
     });
     </script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use the stop function when you intialise .sortable() you can ajax send the new order to a script, which (when you write it!) would save the new order to the database.

```
jQuery(function(){

jQuery("#sortable").sortable({

    stop: function (event, ui) {

        var new_order = jQuery(this).sortable('serialize');
        jQuery.post( "http://www.thissite.com/wp-admin/ajax.php", { action: my_custom_ajax_save, order: new_order }, function( data ) {

            console.log('ajax sent and response received');     

        });
    }
});

})
```

If you give more context we could help with the actual save. For example, if its a post you could save to the postmeta database nicely, what exactly are you saving?